# Why doen't WinMerge refresh seleced folder compare?

Tags: windows-7, winmerge

I am using WinMerge (v 2.14) extensively to compare Git repositories. The code tree is comprised of multiple folders with subfolders and dozens of source files.

When I make changes to a file or a directory in teh tree, I want to refresh the compare on that specific directory. WinMerge provides a menu item (`View` -> `Refresh Selected`), a hotkey (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) and a context menu item for this operation.

However, non of these options does not perform the diff update, and I have to run a full diff (<kbd>F5</kbd>) to refresh the view.

Is this a WinMerge's bug? How to update a subtree diff view?

---

**Update**: I looked at the WinMerge bug tracker and found this report http://sourceforge.net/p/winmerge/bugs/1808/ from 2008, which is still open!

Comment: Have you checked if this potential bug has been reported?

Comment: @Ramhound - to the extent of not finding the subject in a Google search.

Comment: here is the reason I ask.  WinMerge has a bug tracker, forum, and mailing list. All are better places to ask if this behavior is a bug.  If you want to know how to work around this behavior that something that is good for our community.  I just don't have one personally and honestly WinMerge has always perform this way for me.